# Shape parameter vs dispersion in a negative binomial distribution

Tags: modeling, negative-binomial-distribution

For data in a negative binomial distribution, is it possible to derive the dispersion if you only have the mean and shape? I don't have the actual data, just the results summary of mean and shape, but I would like to have dispersion.

I have tried to read up on this but I have not had success.

Comment: Isn't `shape = dispersion` or `shape = 1/dispersion` (depending on the field, likely)?

Comment: No, they are different. I think dispersion combines mean and shape but I'm not sure how. The references I read are not clear on this.

Comment: From what I've seen, variance=mu+shape*mu^2 (or 1/shape) is the usual relationship. Good luck with your search though, the terminology often is very specific to the field.

Answer (score 2):

If the negative binomial is for the number of failures before k successes, i.e. $Y \sim NB(p,k)$ , where p is the probability of success, k is the number of successes, then the dispersion parameter is $1/k$.
Here dispersion takes the same definition as Proc GENMOD in SAS, some books may use the reciprocal, in that way it is k.

Dispersion parameter is from the fact that the variance is inflated than the expectation:
$$E(Y)=\mu$$
$$Var(Y)=\mu+\gamma\mu^2$$
From these two and the usual formula for the expectation and variance for the negative binomial then we can get the dispersion $$\gamma=1/k$$